# C CSV API for unicode

Tags: c, unicode, csv, wchar-t

I need a C API for manipulating CSV data that can work with unicode. I am aware of libcsv (sourceforge.net/projects/libcsv), but I don't think that will work for unicode (please correct me if I'm wrong) because don't see wchar_t being used.

Please advise.

Comment: You might add some informations, which format/encoding your data has, e.g. UTF-8, UTF-16, UTF-32, UCS-2 or whatever.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like libcsv does not use the C string functions to do its work, so it almost works out of the box, in spite of its mbcs/ws ignorance. It treats the string as an array of bytes with an explicit length. This might mostly work for certain wide character encodings that pad out ASCII bytes to fill the width (so newline might be encoded as "\0\n" and space as "\0 "). You could also encode your wide data as UTF-8, which should make things a bit easier. But both approaches might founder on the way libcsv identifies space and line terminator tokens: it expects you to tell it on a byte-to-byte basis whether it's looking at a space or terminator, which doesn't allow for multibyte space/term encodings. You could fix this by modifying the library to pass a pointer into the string and the length left in the string to its space/term test functions, which would be pretty straightforward.